# grunt bower-install and grunt serve ignoring main files in my root bower.json, using Yeoman

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, yeoman, bower

I'm new to Yeoman and Bower so I'm a bit confused. I'm using Yeoman to build a client web app. I want to load a custom css file called test.css into my index.html.

I have seen that the bower_components libs specify which files should be loaded on index.html in the main section of the bower.json file, so I'm trying to do the same with my own app but is not working. I don't see any changes on index.html after running

grunt bower-install
grunt serve

Here is my bower.json file:

```
{
  "name": "myApp",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "main": [
    "app/styles/test.css"
  ],
  "dependencies": {
    "angular": "1.2.6",
    "json3": "~3.2.6",
    "es5-shim": "~2.1.0",
    "jquery": "~1.10.2",
    "sass-bootstrap": "~3.0.2",
    "angular-resource": "1.2.6",
    "angular-cookies": "1.2.6",
    "angular-sanitize": "1.2.6",
    "angular-route": "1.2.6",
    "ng-flow": "~2",
    "angular-bootstrap": "~0.10.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "angular-mocks": "1.2.6",
    "angular-scenario": "1.2.6"
  }
}
```

I also have tried different ways to call test.css:

```
"styles/test.css",
"/styles/test.css",
"app/styles/test.css",
"./app/styles/test.css",
"./test.css"
```

My project structure is the following

```
.
├── Gruntfile.js
├── README.md
├── app
│   ├── 404.html
│   ├── bower_components
│   ├── config.js
│   ├── favicon.ico
│   ├── images
│   ├── index.html
│   ├── robots.txt
│   ├── scripts
│   ├── styles
│   │   ├── main.scss
│   │   └── test.css
│   └── views
├── bower.json
├── dist
├── karma-e2e.conf.js
├── karma.conf.js
├── node_modules
├── package.json
└── test
```

I know that I can add this file manually but I think is cleaner to have everything specified on the bower.json file. ¿Is there any way to specify custom files in bower.json on it's *main* value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `bower.json` file you're editing represents your application. Your application itself isn't a Bower package. In other words, you probably don't want to publish your application to the Bower package repository for others to use in their applications.

`grunt-bower-install` (which is just a wrapper for [`wiredep`](https://github.com/stephenplusplus/wiredep)) works well for Bower packages, but isn't meant to support application files. There may be other tools that meet your needs, but in general, it's best to just manually include references to your application files where they belong.